# DuplicateIdentifier: xamarin.ios.xamarin-framework when trying to install Xamarin app to iPhone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

This has just started today, so I'm not sure what may have changed.  When I try to launch my App from Xamarin Studio, I get an error that it failed to install

DuplicateIdentifier: Found bundle at /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Qqep3q/extracted/MyApp/Frameworks/Xamarin.framework with the same identifier (xamarin.ios.xamarin-framework) as bundle at /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Qqep3q/extracted/IosGold.app/Frameworks/Xamarin-debug.framework
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/c/imaging/bin/iPhone/Debug/MyApp.app' on the device 'C's iPhone': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe80000b0 (This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains. Bundle identifiers must be unique.).

I've tried restarting Xamarin studio and have done a clean and rebuild, but with the same results.  Any ideas on what might have causes this and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: manually delete your bin and obj folders

Comment: @Gandalf458 I've tried that.  But, to be sure, I just tried it again.  No luck.  It starts to install, and then it gets to PreflightingApplication - PercentComplete: 30% and gives the same "Bundle identifiers must be unique" error.

Comment: Darn. It worked for me to delete bin and obj folders on the main app and the extension.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue yesterday and spent many hours on it, upgrading Xcode, Visual Studio without any success.

This morning I disassociated my extension from the main iOS project, performed a clean from the top-level project, ran the app (all okay - it deployed!), then re-associated the extension and ran again (still all okay!).

Not sure why removing the extension -> deploy -> re-associate made a difference.

Note I also re-installed from the AppStore once, so maybe that helped flush something too.

Comment: Hi Robbie, just here to say you are my hero of the day. I was going nuts with this.

Comment: Robbie is right. We have to install the app without the extension to be able to -upgrade?- the app with the extension. There is no way we could deploy the app with its extension without a previously deployed version without the extension-at least from Visual Studio for Mac.